# Insert data in Ancestor Table and retrieve data from Ancestor Table

Tags: sql-server, database, hierarchy, ancestor

I am trying to create an Ancestor Table for Prerequisite Units. I am not sure how to insert data using SQL script for Level 2, 3, so on...

I have three tables:

1. Unit_Of_Competency (Unit_Of_Competency_ID: uniqueidentifier, UoC_Code: varchar(20), UoC_Title: varchar(200), Descriptor: varchar(500))
2. Prerequisite (ID: uniqueidentifier, Unit_Of_Competency_ID: foreign key references Unit_Of_Competency_ID, Prerequisite_ID: foreign key references Unit_Of_Competency_ID)
3. Prerequisite_Ancestor (Prerequisite_Ancestor_ID, Unit_Of_Competency_ID: foreign key references Unit_Of_Competency_ID, Prerequisite_ID: foreign key references Unit_Of_Competency_ID)

Unit Of Competency Table has the following Data:

[image: Unit Of Competency Table]

Prerequisite Table has the following Data:

[image: Prerequisite Table]

On joining Unit_Of_Competency and Prerequisite we get the following output:

[image: Joined Tables]

I need to populate the Prerequisite_Ancestor table; I have only populated till Level 1

[image: Prerequisite Ancestor Table]

I need to populate the Ancestor Table for Level 2, 3, 4
For example,

1. Bayes Theorem || Division    || 2
2. Probability   || Mathematics || 2
3. Bayes Theorem || Mathematics || 3

The way I have entered Ancestor_Level 1 in Prerequisite_Ancestor table is using the following script:

```
INSERT INTO Prerequisite_Ancestor (Prerequisite_Ancestor_ID, UoC_ID, Prerequisite_ID, Ancestor_Level)
select newID(), U.Unit_Of_Competency_ID as UoC, P.Prerequisite_ID as Prerequisite, 1 from Prerequisite P 
join Unit_Of_Competency U on P.Unit_Of_Competency_ID=U.Unit_Of_Competency_ID
join Unit_Of_Competency U2 on U2.Unit_Of_Competency_ID=P.Prerequisite_ID
```

How do I enter the Levels 2, 3, ... using script?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another table which is used for staging purposes which would gather the data from the web form you design. And truncate everytime for a new form submission. The staging table would consist of all the columns you require in order to populate all the three tables. Looking at your existing columns, the staging table would look like it has the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE LoadUnitsStg(
    StagingID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    UoC_Code VARCHAR(50),
    UoC_Title VARCHAR(200),
    UoC_Descriptor VARCHAR(500),
    Pre_UoC_Code VARCHAR(50),
    Pre_UoC_PreReq VARCHAR(50),
    Pre_Pathway VARCHAR(50),
    Anc_UoC_Code VARCHAR(50),
    Anc_UoC_PreReq VARCHAR(50),
    Ancestor_level INT
    )
```

Now load the data from the web form to the staging table and use this query to populate the data into your required tables.

```
INSERT INTO Unit_Of_Competency ([UoC_Code],[UoC_Title],[Descriptor])
        SELECT DISTINCT(UoC_Code),UoC_Title,UoC_Descriptor FROM LoadUnitsStg stg
            WHERE UoC_Code IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM Unit_Of_Competency UoC
                    WHERE UoC.UoC_Code=stg.UoC_Code);

    INSERT INTO Prerequisite ([Pathway],[Unit_Of_Competency_ID],[Prerequisite_ID])
        SELECT DISTINCT(Pre_Pathway),(Select Unit_Of_Competency_ID from Unit_Of_Competency where UoC_Code like stg.Pre_UoC_Code),(Select Unit_Of_Competency_ID as Prerequisite_ID from Unit_Of_Competency where UoC_Code like stg.Pre_UoC_PreReq) FROM LoadUnitsStg stg
            WHERE Pre_Pathway IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM Prerequisite Pre
                    WHERE Pre.Pathway=stg.Pre_Pathway);

    INSERT INTO Prerequisite_Ancestor ([Ancestor_Level],[UoC_ID],[Prerequisite_ID])
        SELECT DISTINCT(Ancestor_level),(Select Unit_Of_Competency_ID as UoC_ID from Unit_Of_Competency where UoC_Code like stg.Anc_UoC_Code),(Select Unit_Of_Competency_ID as Prerequisite_ID from Unit_Of_Competency where UoC_Code like stg.Anc_UoC_PreReq) FROM LoadUnitsStg stg
            WHERE Ancestor_level IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM Prerequisite_Ancestor Anc
                    WHERE Anc.Ancestor_level=stg.Ancestor_level);
```

Upon loading the data, just truncate the staging table for next set of entries.

Hope this helps you.